# Map in groovy, how to get value from key?

Tags: groovy, syntax

I have map

```
def loginEmail = [
  "abc": "abc@mail.ru",
  "cde": "cde@mail.ru"
]
```

How can I get value from method?
Something like that:

```
def getEmail(String login){
  return loginEmail.get(login)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `loginEmail[login]`? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @ernest_k It is question about syntax. My example do not work, how to fix it with groovy syntax?

Comment: what you have, and what I mentioned, should both work. What error are you getting?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the error in your question, then only we can understand what u r looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying your code in the Groovy console I get the following error:

```
Exception thrown

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: loginEmail for class: ConsoleScript9
    at ConsoleScript9.getEmail(ConsoleScript9:7)
    at ConsoleScript9.run(ConsoleScript9:10)
```

I thought of two options to overcome this. You can pass both the key and the map so you can return the corresponding value from the method. Something like this:

```
def loginEmail = [
  "abc": "abc@mail.ru",
  "cde": "cde@mail.ru"
]

def getEmail(String login, Map<String, String> loginEmail){
  return loginEmail[login]
}

def result = getEmail("abc", loginEmail)

println(result)
```

Or make the map as the property of a class and then call it via class method like:

```
class TestLogin {

    static loginEmail = [
      "abc": "abc@mail.ru",
      "cde": "cde@mail.ru"
    ]

    static getEmail(String login){
      return loginEmail[login]
    }
}

TestLogin.getEmail('abc')
```

Answer (score 2):

A very groovy way to do this:

```
def loginEmail = [
        "abc": "abc@mail.ru",
        "cde": "cde@mail.ru"
    ]

def getEmail(login) {
    loginEmail."$login"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought you are asking about the scope problem in groovy. 
If It is, please find the answer below

```
def val1 = "hi"  // This can't be used inside a method
val2 = "hai"  // This can be used as it is global
```

So in your case declare map as,

```
loginEmail = [
  "abc": "abc@mail.ru",
  "cde": "cde@mail.ru"
]
```

instead of `def loginEmail`.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You code should work except you have some scoping problems.

The following example shows a working implementation in combination with a [spockframework](http://spockframework.org) test.

```
package x.y.z

import spock.lang.Specification

class LoginLockupSpec extends Specification {

    def "test different ways to lookup email by login"() {
        given:
        def loginLookup = new LoginLookup()

        expect: 'getMail Method returns mail'
        loginLookup.getEmail('abc') == "abc@mail.ru"

        and: 'direct map access is also possible'
        loginLookup.loginEmail.abc == "abc@mail.ru"
        loginLookup.loginEmail['cde'] == "cde@mail.ru"
        loginLookup.loginEmail.get('cde') == "cde@mail.ru"
    }
}


class LoginLookup {

    def loginEmail = [
            "abc": "abc@mail.ru",
            "cde": "cde@mail.ru"
    ]

    def getEmail(String login) {
        return loginEmail.get(login)
    }
}
```